# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: SIGBUS while installing ZAP proxy in parrot home OS

Tags: jvm, owasp, zap, openjdk-11, parrot

I was trying to install the ZAP proxy in my parrot home OS, but I'm unable to install it and the error that I'm receiving in the terminal is as follows:

```
(A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
 SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f904544b12f, pid=6446, tid=6447JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime 
 Environment (11.0.5+10) (build 11.0.5+10-post-Debian-2)
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.5+10-post-Debian-2, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, 
 compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [libjvm.so+0xcce12f]
 No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
 (https://bugs.debian.org/openjdk-11)

Aborted
```

Comment: I'm confused the first half of your sentence says you installed it, then you say you're not able to install it. Which is it? What are you running when you receive that error? This seems like more of a parrot issue than a zap issue.

Comment: Agree with Kingthorin. Also what install were you trying to use? The cross platform package would probably be best - thats just a zip file of the release.

Comment: Sorry Simon, actually what I meant is I downloaded it in my parrot linux system and it is a .sh file but when I use terminal "chmod 777 or chmod +x" command to install it , it throws error that I've already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Kingthorin, Simon Bennets I will try with the zap cross platform package.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
(A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
 SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f904544b12f, pid=6446, tid=6447JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime 
 Environment (11.0.5+10) (build 11.0.5+10-post-Debian-2)
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.5+10-post-Debian-2, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, 
 compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [libjvm.so+0xcce12f]
```

...implies that the `V` frame was the *Problematic frame* which crashed which resulted in **`libjvm.so`** file.

The crash you observed is possibly not a [zap](/questions/tagged/zap) or [java](/questions/tagged/java) issue but a [debian](/questions/tagged/debian) issue.

---

### Deep Dive

However as per the documentation in [What versions of Java are supported?](https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/what-versions-of-java-are-supported/) page, ZAP should be able to run with all/newer Java versions, but might require a minimum for certain ZAP versions:

- ZAP 2.7.0 and later requires a minimum of Java 1.8
- ZAP 2.0.0 and later requires a minimum of Java 1.7
- Previous versions of ZAP also support Java 1.6, the last of those being 1.4.1

Additionally, as per the documentation in [Download ZAP](https://www.zaproxy.org/download/) page:

- The Windows and Linux versions require Java 8 or higher to run.
- The macOS version includes Java 8 - you can use the Linux or Cross Platform versions if you do not want to download this.

Finally, as per the documentation in [Release 2.9.0](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/releases/2.9.0/) page:

> This is a bug fix and enhancement release, which requires a minimum of Java 8. Note that a minimum of Java 11 is recommended, especially for high DPI displays.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Jvm crash :fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128783/jvm-crash-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment)
- [“A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment” when running java project on another computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40638312/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-when-running-j)
- [A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment (SIGBUS (0x7))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554542/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-sigbus-0x7)
- [JVM crashes with problematic frame [libjvm.so+0x7f582e] PerfLongVariant::sample()+0x1e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273800/jvm-crashes-with-problematic-frame-libjvm-so0x7f582e-perflongvariantsample)